# Mysterious unstyled horizontal line when styling QDockWidget with Qt 5

Tags: css, qt, qt5, stylesheet

We recently updated our Qt application from Qt 4.8 to Qt 5.12 and that caused a few styling regressions, among which this one:

[image: Horizontal bar appears unstyled]

This horizontal bar used to appear dark gray as per our stylesheet but it now appears in a light shade of gray that stands out too much.

Here are the relevant bits of stylesheet:

```
QWidget
{
    background-color: DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_COLOR;
    color: DEFAULT_TEXT_COLOR;
    border: 0px;
    selection-color: SELECTED_TEXT_COLOR;
    selection-background-color: SELECTED_BACKGROUND_COLOR;
}

...

QDockWidget::title
{
    background-color: ACTIVE_BACKGROUND_COLOR;
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-top: 6px;
}

QDockWidget::close-button,
QDockWidget::float-button
{
    border: 0px;
}

QDockWidget::float-button:hover,
QDockWidget::close-button:hover
{
    background-color: HOVER_BACKGROUND_COLOR;
}
```

(Values in upper case are macros that get expanded to their definition at load time.)

I tried setting the text and border colors of `QDockWidget` and `QTabWidget::pane` but that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Adding

```
QTabBar
{
    qproperty-drawBase: 0;
}
```

solves the problem.